# react native error messages not understood

Tags: react-native

I have the following react native script.  It's not quite right yet but getting there.  In the console I'm getting the following messages that I don't understand what to do with:

```
Warning: componentWillMount is deprecated and will be removed in the next 
major version. Use componentDidMount instead. As a temporary workaround, you 
can rename to UNSAFE_componentWillMount.

Please update the following components: ExpoRootComponent, 
RootErrorBoundary, Text, TextInput, View

Learn more about this warning here:
react-async-component-lifecycle-hooks
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\YellowBox.js:82:15 in warn
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer- 
dev.js:5706:19 in printWarning
- ... 21 more stack frames from framework internals
14:17:34: Warning: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated and will be 
removed in the next major version. Use static getDerivedStateFromProps 
instead.

Please update the following components: Text, TextInput, View

Learn more about this warning here:
react-async-component-lifecycle-hooks
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\YellowBox.js:82:15 in warn
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer- 
dev.js:5706:19 in printWarning
- ... 21 more stack frames from framework internals
```

I'm not explicitly calling componentWillMount.  How do I use componentDidMount to get rid of the warning?

How do I update the components it's asking me to update?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput,Button, StyleSheet, View,Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import {Constants} from 'expo'

  let id=0
  const Todo = (props) => (
    <Text>
      {/* <input type='checkbox'
              checked={props.todo.checked}
              onClick={props.onToggle}
        /> */}
       <Button title='delete' button onPress={props.onDelete}></Button>
       <Text>{props.todo.text}</Text>
    </Text>
  )
  export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
      super()
      this.state={
        todos:[],
      }
    }



  addTodo(e){
   console.log('hello')
    console.log(e.target)
    this.setState({todos: [...this.state.todos,
                              { id:id++,
                                text: e.value,
                                checked:false
                              }
                          ]
                  })
    e.value=''
  }
  toggle(id){
    this.setState({todos: this.state.todos.map(todo=>{
                          if(id!==todo.id)return todo
                          return{
                              id:todo.id,
                              text:todo.text,
                              checked: !todo.checked}})})
  }
  removeTodo(id){
    this.setState({todos: this.state.todos.filter(todo=>(todo.id!==id))})
  }

  render(){
     return(

       <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text >Count of Todos: &nbsp;{this.state.todos.length}</Text>
          <Text >{"Todo's checked:"}&nbsp;
               {this.state.todos.filter(todo =>(todo.checked===true)).length}</Text>
          <TextInput
                 style={{height:25,borderColor:'red',borderWidth:1,textAlign:'center'}}
                  placeholder={'add ToDo'}
                  onSubmitEditing={(e)=>(this.addTodo(e.target))}/>

          <ScrollView>
           {this.state.todos.map(todo=>(
                 <Todo
                    onToggle={()=>(this.toggle(todo.id))}
                    onDelete={()=>(this.removeTodo(todo.id))}
                    todo={todo}
                    key={todo.id}
                 />))}
          </ScrollView>
       </View>
     )
    }
  }
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    flexDirection:'column',
    height:50,

    paddingTop:3*Constants.statusBarHeight,

  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillMount` is deprecated in React 16.3 or React Native 0.55, which are just released days ago. Since most libraries (yeah, including Expo) haven't been updated to replace these deprecated APIs, you can safely ignore these warnings now, or upgrade to React Native 0.55.2 which suppresses these lifecycle warnings.

Related discussion: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18175